# Does my app’s iOS App Store phased rollout get halted when I submit a new build for review?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect, developer-program

We have a build in phased rollout, currently at 5%. We're looking to submit a new build for review that we plan to release when the current build hits 100%.

If we submit the new build for review, does it halt the rollout of the current build, or does the rollout continue until you release the new build?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  If you’ve already [opened a support ticket with Apple](https://developer.apple.com/contact/), perhaps indicate that with an edit. If not, perhaps document and search for the topic Apple has published on how this works.  You may get some close votes / down votes as this looks like exactly what [vendor customer support](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2508/5472) and basic [App Store documentation](https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/update-your-app/release-a-version-update-in-phases/) is designed to answer.

Comment: Unfortunately the documentation isn't very clear on this specific scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From experience, the rollout continues unless you manually pause the rollout.